# Filter a JSON view by day and time without using Date?

Tags: 7, views

I created a JSON View, using the Views Datasource module, of a content type that has a time field, using the Time Field module, and a Weekday, using the Weekdays Field module. I am not using the Date module. Now, I need to filter this view showing me only the content that has been registered today and now (or at lest in a time that's before the next registered time in the content type, and after the time the current type content is)

For example, this content type is called Radio Program. The user inputs a radio program with a time and a weekday associated with it. The time the user inputs is only the starting time of the radio program, not the total time.

How do I filter this, so that I get the needed JSON? I'm a bit new to Drupal.

Comment: Why aren't you using date?

Comment: Date is always linked to a Gregorian Calendar, so it's really cumbersome to use when you only need a time of day, unlinked to at least a year, which is the current case. I'm using Date in other parts of the site and it works great, but here is just not viable.

Comment: The problem is that you need to filter in relation to something else - I'm assuming you want the filter to work automatically and not require user input?

Comment: Exactly, it needs to be automatic. In this case, I need to filter it with the current time and day (now it's wednesday at 3:40 pm, show the current program). Remember that this view creates a JSON, later fed to a mobile app.

Comment: In that case, you probably really want to use date, and just not show the year in your date format. I believe you'd then use contextual filters to pass in the current date/time.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, there's a relative date portion of the date filter. That would give you what you need.

But I really do think you'll have to use date.

Comment: Do you know how to do it (hide the year)? I don't know how to. Besides, in the add-node form I need the user to input a weekday, not a full date, I didn't saw how to do that with Date.

Comment: Create a date format that doesn't display the year. You would use the values that PHP uses to format dates for your display format. As for the user, let me check, I believe you can specify in the widget the format you want the user to add a date.

Comment: I still need to filter with a weekday (monday, tuesday, etc.), and I need that the user can input the weekday when creating a new Radio Program, I didn't see a way to do this using Date, do you know how to?

Comment: Let me check, it'll be a few hours.